# Javascript error

Tags: javascript

I get an error "popup undefined" anyone know why?

here is my code
edit: http://jsfiddle.net/aDFSR/13/

edit:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">

 var popupInstance = null;

 function createCrossBrowserPopup(){
     alert("creating");
     return new _popup();
 }

 function _popup() {
     this.wnd = null;
     this.hiddenFrame = null; //workaround for IE 6 - with divs and select (divs are appearing behind select elements)
     this.showHiddenFrame = showHiddenFrame;
     this.displayPopupContainer = displayPopupContainer;
     this.html = "";
     this.setHTML = _setHTML;
     this.show = _show;
     this.hide = _hide;
     this.triggerElementId = null;
     this.blur = null;
 }

 function _setHTML(html, event) {
     this.html = html;
     if (this.wnd != null) {
         this.wnd.html(this.html);
     }

     if (event != null)
         stopEventPropagation(event, null);
 }

 /// leftOffset: the left offset of the popup
 /// topOffset: the top offset of the popup
 /// width: the width of the popup
 /// height: the height of the popup
 /// element: the element which causes the popup to be opened
 /// event: the event which cased the popup to be opened
 function _show(leftOffset, topOffset, width, height, element, event) {

          // Hide previous popup if existed
     if (popupInstance != null && element.id != popupInstance.triggerElementId) {
         popupInstance.hide();
         return;
     }

     // if popupInstance != null this means that the same popup was called, makes no sense to create it again
     if (popupInstance == null){
         leftOffset = leftOffset != null ? leftOffset : 0;
         topOffset = topOffset != null ? topOffset : 0;

         this.displayPopupContainer(element, width, height, leftOffset, topOffset);

         //workaround for IE 6 - with divs and select (divs are appearing behind select elements)
         this.showHiddenFrame(element, width, height, leftOffset, topOffset);
         // end of workaround

         setElementsPosition(element, leftOffset, topOffset);

         // save the id, onblur event of the element that fires the popup
         // and also save the instance of this object - for $(document).click and $(window).resize
         this.triggerElementId = element.id;
         this.blur = element.onblur;
         element.onblur = null;
         popupInstance = this;
     }

     stopEventPropagation(event);
 }

 function _hide() {
     $(".modal_popup_container").hide();
     if (this.triggerElementId != null) {
         // Assign  back the blur event (using simple Javascript, not jQuery as it is  causing onblur to be fired 2 times) and reset some variables
         $('#' + this.triggerElementId)[0].onblur = this.blur;
         if ($.isFunction(this.blur)) {
             $('#' + this.triggerElementId)[0].onblur();
         }
         else
         if(typeof(this.blur) == 'string')
         {
             var regex = new RegExp('(?=[\w.])this(?!\w)/g');
             eval(this.blur.replace(regex, '$(\'#' + this.triggerElementId + '\')[0]'));
         }

         // reset variables
         this.triggerElementId = null;
         this.blur = null;
         popupInstance = null;
     }
 }

 function displayPopupContainer(element, width, height, leftOffset, topOffset) {
     if (this.wnd == null) {
         this.wnd = $('<div />');
         this.wnd.addClass('modal_popup_container');
         this.wnd.css({
                 'position' : 'absolute',
                 'z-index' : '999',
                 'margin' : '0'});
     }

     this.wnd.css({ 'width': width, 'height': height });
     this.wnd.html(this.html);
     this.wnd.show();

     var parentElement = $(element).parent();
     $(parentElement).append(this.wnd);
 }

 function showHiddenFrame(element, width, height, leftOffset, topOffset) {
     if (this.hiddenFrame == null) {
         this.hiddenFrame = $('<iframe />');
         this.hiddenFrame.addClass('modal_popup_container');

         this.hiddenFrame.attr({
             "src": "javascript:'&lt;html&gt;&lt;/html&gt;';",
             "scrolling": "no",
             "frameborder": 0
         });
         this.hiddenFrame.css({
             "position": "absolute",
             "border": "none",
             "display": "block",
             "z-index": "998",
             "margin": "0"
         });
     }

     this.hiddenFrame.css({ "width": width, "height": height });
     this.hiddenFrame.show();

     var parentElement = $(element).parent();
     $(parentElement).append(this.hiddenFrame);
 }

 function setElementsPosition(element, leftOffset, topOffset) {
     $(".modal_popup_container").position({
         my: "left top",
         at: "left bottom",
         of: $(element),
         offset: leftOffset + " " + topOffset,
         collision: "fit"
     });
 }

 function stopEventPropagation(event)
 {
     // manage FireFox and IE events, check if event was passed, else try and get window.event
     var e = (!event) ? window.event : event;
     // avoid that the current click event propagates up
     if (typeof (e) != "undefined") {
         if (e.stopPropagation)
             e.stopPropagation();
         else e.cancelBubble = true;
     }
 }

 // hide the popup when user clicks outside it
 $(document).click(
     function(event) {
         if ($(event.target).closest('.modal_popup_container').get(0) == null
         && popupInstance != null) {
             popupInstance.hide();
         }
     });

 $(window).resize(
     function(event) {
         if (popupInstance != null) {
             popupInstance.hide();
         }
     });

 </script>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var popup = createCrossBrowserPopup();
  popup.setHTML("<div style='width:100%; height:100%;
 background-color:#AAFFEE;border-width: 2px; border-color: silver; border-style:
 solid;' onclick='changePopupHTML();'> test </div>", null);

 function changePopupHTML() {
     popup.setHTML("<div style='width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#AA11EE;border-width: 2px; border-color: silver; border-style: solid;'> test222 </div>", null);
 }

 </script
<body>

<input type="text" id="txtExample" onclick="popup.show(25, 0, 100, 50, this, event);" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle is all jacked up. Might want to look at it again and get it all setup properly. Also you have quite a few typo's... misplaced unclosed tags etc.

Comment: @loktar what's wrong with it? it looks fine to me

Comment: I did c/p to your code an it's working. what's the problem ?

Comment: In JSFiddle you are using mootools, and trying to include jquery, using script tags in the js portion of it. You have a script tag missing the closing >, you also have the body inside of the head tag, and multiple redundant script tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second edit: In your latest version, the problem is that the javascript you enter in the javascript frame appears in the head tag. You're then referencing the variable from the body tag. This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/E9DrH/

Comment: i dont understand. popup is declared at towards the end of the page var popup = createCrossBrowserPopup(); so why is it saying its not defined